# How can I add this specific bar?

Tags: java, android, xml, variables, styles

I want to add a few bars to my app that will get filled by a variable. When someone for example selects 20, the variable will get updated by +20 and a progress bar should be filled in relation to that updated variable. How can I implement such a progress bar?

Thank you in advance,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using the android [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) or the android [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). You should check out the documentation on [Developer.Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). You'll generally find solutions there :D

Hope I Helped :D

Comment: Yes, ProgressBar works pretty good, thank you! Do you know how I can add a Text inside the bar? Couldn't find it on Developer.Android :D